# Github Action : rsync setup keeps on failing

Tags: github, github-actions

I have a workflow as `deployment.yml` which looks like this:

```
name: Deployment

on:
  push:
    branches: [ production ]

jobs:
  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2

    - uses: actions/setup-node@v1.1.0
      with:
        version: 10.x

    - name: Install dependencies
      run: |
        composer install -o
        yarn
    - name: Build
      run: yarn build:production
    
    - name: Sync
      env:
        dest: 'user@server:/var/www/html/wp-content/themes/theme-name'
      run: |
        echo "${{secrets.DEPLOY_KEY}}" > deploy_key
        chmod 600 ./deploy_key
        rsync -chav --delete \
          -e 'ssh -i ./deploy_key -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no' \
          --exclude /deploy_key \
          --exclude /.git/ \
          --exclude /.github/ \
          --exclude /node_modules/ \
          ./ ${{env.dest}}
```

When this action executes I get an error at `Sync` step with the following error.

```
Run echo "***" > deploy_key
  echo "***" > deploy_key
  chmod 600 ./deploy_key
  rsync -chav --delete \
    -e 'ssh -i ./deploy_key -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no' \
    --exclude /deploy_key \
    --exclude /.git/ \
    --exclude /.github/ \
    --exclude /node_modules/ \
    ./ root@111.11.111.111:/var/www/html/wp-content/themes/theme-name
  shell: /bin/bash -e {0}
  env:
    dest: root@159.89.165.152:/var/www/html/wp-content/themes/theme-name
Warning: Permanently added '111.11.111.111' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
Load key "./deploy_key": invalid format
Permission denied, please try again.
Permission denied, please try again.
root@111.11.111.111: Permission denied (publickey,password).
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [sender]
rsync error: unexplained error (code 255) at io.c(235) [sender=3.1.2]
##[error]Process completed with exit code 255.
```

This is a Digital Ocean droplet with SSH key set and added to Authorized keys.
Also inside me repository setting
I added them to:

1. Deploy Keys : as DEPLOY_KEY
2. Secrets : as DEPLOY_KEY [I added this because earlier in the error area Deploy keys output was blank.]

Is my setup wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found that the reason my code was not running is because of the fact that I kept on adding the public key in my secrets `DEPLOY_KEY`.

You have to add your `private key` as the secret.
Also you shouldn't forget to add your public to the `authorized_keys` list or else your action will fail.

This is the final `deployment.yml` file which I used.

```
name: Deployment

on:
  push:
    branches: [ production ]

jobs:
  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2

    - uses: actions/setup-node@v1.1.0
      with:
        version: 12.x

    - name: Install dependencies
      run: |
        composer install -o
        yarn
    - name: Build
      run: yarn build
      
    - name: Sync
      env:
        dest: 'root@111.11.111.111:/var/www/html/wp-content/themes/theme-name' // Change here
      run: |
        echo "${{secrets.DEPLOY_KEY}}" > deploy_key
        chmod 600 ./deploy_key
        rsync -chav --delete \
          -e 'ssh -i ./deploy_key -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no' \
          --exclude /deploy_key \
          --exclude /.git/ \
          --exclude /.github/ \
          --exclude /node_modules/ \
          ./ ${{env.dest}}
```

This particular deployment is used for [sage](https://roots.io/docs/sage/9.x/installation/) - a WordPress starter theme and is deployed in the digital ocean droplet having [openlitespeed](https://marketplace.digitalocean.com/apps/openlitespeed-wordpress) server.

> I wrote [a post](https://bhanusingh.in/deploying-sagewordpress-starter-theme-to-your-host-using-github-actions) explaining the complete deployment process for sage-roots.